# Admin dashboard for microservice application

Tags: laravel, microservices

I am working on an admin dashboard for 5 services using `Laravel`. It is really complicated to do so in admin. We, for example, want to show a list of `transactions` with user name for each row. Both of the `users` and `transactions` tables are in different databases. We had to make another request to fetch the user name form the other service.

I am wondering about when it comes to statistics and writing complex queries to get data from all of theses services in a report. How can I handle such a case?

Can I make multiple connections to the databases with the admin dashboard project?
Is there any available pattern that facilitate the work for me?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. As of now, this question isn't proper fit for the site since it covers a broad topic with multiple questions at the same time. You need narrow it down. What you can do is,  try different patterns and if you get stuck, then you should post a question about what is not working.

Comment: Great thanks. I just want to have a discussion about all of these topics.

Comment: Well.... Try other forums. Questions regarding opinions will get closed anyway since that doesn't fit question answer format.

Comment: Well that's really shortsighted. I have this exact same problem (one admin panel for multiple services), and I would like to see what others have come up with to solve that problem. He has a very specific problem, for which there might be a very specific answer. But we'll never know, because the question is closed. ‍♂️